# How to apply standard to all subgoals in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

To prove an equality "A = B" one can prove two inclusions "A ⊆ B" and "B ⊆ A". Now, I'm using the method "standard" to transform this goal into the goal "fix x in A and show x is in B". However, I don't know how to do this on all subgoals.

How can I do this in Isabelle?

Comment: I don't get all of your question. Are you familiar with proof method expressions (https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf#subsection.6.4.1) or looking for something more fancy?

If you just want to break up your intial goal into the usual subgoals, I'd suggest starting off with `proof safe`!

Comment: @BenKeks thanks for your comment, please don't delete it. It is a very good reference! On the other hand, the ; as explained below does the job (is also explained in your reference.

Comment: another option: if you import `HOL-Eisbach.Eisbach` you can use `apply (all ‹standard›)`.

Comment: @peq I added your comment to my answer: I hope you do not mind. If you post it as an explicit answer, I will try to upvote it (if I do not forget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to add [peq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303637/peq)'s comment to my answer

> if you import `HOL-Eisbach.Eisbach` you can use `apply(all‹standard›)`

---

If multiple goals emerge from a single goal as a result of an application of a method, then you can use semicolon `;` (structural composition: see section 6.4 in Isar-ref) to apply the next method to all emerging subgoals, i.e.

```
lemma "(A::'a set) = B ∧ (C::'a set) = D"
  apply (intro conjI; standard; standard)
  oops
```

---

As a side remark, I do not believe that repeated application of `standard` is considered to be a very good style. For example, for your use case, normally, I use

```
lemma "(A::'a set) = B"
  apply(intro subset_antisym subsetI)
  oops
```

Hopefully, it should be sufficiently easy to see how you can also apply this method to multiple subgoals simultaneously.

---

Isabelle version: Isabelle2020

---